# Google Calendar API, filter on "busy" status

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to filter the events that are returned from the google API, depending on the "busy" status. From what I have seen, this is not possible. The only workaround that I found, is using the "transparency" key, that seems to be only present if the event is marked as "available".

The above workaround still requires to fetch all events, and then remove the ones from the response, that fail the above check. The /busyFree endpoint, seems to only for for calendars, not specifc events. Am I missing something? Is there indeed no way to only fetch events that are marked as busy/not busy?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Thanks, I'm however not new to StackOverflow. Feel free to point out what you believe is wrong about my question. It's a question that can be answered and there is no code required. Thanks for the downvote and close vote :)

Comment: The question has no code, and in general is far too broad.

Comment: As said above, there is no code required, otherwise point me to the rule that says so. Not too sure what is "too broad" about it, thanks for your opinion though.

Comment: Feel free to ignore me and wait for an answer form someone else that disagrees with me. But maybe read the first 2 lines of [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: "software tools commonly used by programmers" and is
"a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". Those seem to match my question. Thanks for your input though, let me know if something specific is missing :)

Comment: I am not going to join in an argument!

Comment: Me neither, was just trying to figure out what might be missing in my question. Have a great day anyways!

Comment: It would seem you're looking for this: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy

Comment: I looked at the endpoint, I am not sure what it is supposed to return, there is almost no description and their request test option does not return me any calendars/events, even though I have calendars that contain entries that have been marked as bussy as well ones that have been marked as "not busy".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed there is currently no way to filter out non busy events other than doing it yourself. If you only care about when the user is busy and not the details of the events, you can use the free busy query instead (that does filter out non busy meetings)